# Markers not exported to mp4

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have tried the sample code to move a camera along a path:
https://github.com/mapbox/impact-tools/tree/master/journey-animation-sequence

Sample code is working fine and I can export the animation to mp4

When I try to use markers I can see the markers on the screens during the animation but markers are not exported to the mp4 video. Any idea ?

```
    const pinRoute = trackGeojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates;

    const startMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
      color: 'red',
      scale: 0.8,
      draggable: false,
      pitchAlignment: 'auto',
      rotationAlignment: 'auto'
    })
        .setLngLat(pinRoute[0])
        .addTo(map)

    const endMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
      color: 'green',
      scale: 0.8,
      draggable: false,
      pitchAlignment: 'auto',
      rotationAlignment: 'auto'
    })
        .setLngLat(pinRoute[pinRoute.length-1])
        .addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Markers are not exported in the video due the fact that only canvas draw is exported.

Markers are not par of the canvas layer

Answer (score -1):

maybe use a different library or technique to add the markers.